# Meteor reactive sources

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

I have an app where there are 5 collections: one for books, one for types (of books, like fantasy, sci-fi...), one for the languages, one for the subscribtions (including type_id, lang_id and user_id) and last one if Meteor.users.

I created this helper function to retrieve the books fitting the subscribtions of each user (I'm using angular-meteor)

```
$scope.helpers({
userBooks:function(){
            var subBooks=[];
            var books;
            var user_id=Meteor.userId();
            Subscribtions.find({user_id:user_id}).forEach(function(sub){
                books=Books.find({type_id:sub.type_id,lang_id:sub.lang_id}).fetch();
                for(var i=0;i<books.length;i++){
                    subBooks.push(books[i]);
                }
            });
            return subBooks;
        }
})
```

Suppose that a new book or a new subscribtions is added, or another user logs it, would the subBooks data updates? is it considered reactive (because it contains reactive data)?

Comment: You are making things very complicated: you can simply return the cursor on Books.find (i.e. just `return Book.find(...);` to your template.
As soon as you fetch, you get data. A cursor is reactive, but the data once fetched is not.

Comment: Would it work even if I did a return inside Subscribtion.find(...).forEach()?

Comment: Would *not* work if you return from inside the forEach as you'd only be returning to the parent scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you simplify this and publish an already joined collection of `Subscriptions` and `Books` from the server using the [reywood:publish-composite](https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite) package.

Server:

```
Meteor.publishComposite('mySubs', {
  find: function() { // Find all the subscriptions for the current user        
    return Subscriptions.find({ userId: this.userId });
  },
  children: [
    {
      find: function(sub) { // find books related to the current subscription 'sub'            
        return Books.find({ type_id: sub.type_id, lang_id: sub.lang_id});
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

On the client:

```
Meteor.subscribe('mySubs');
```

Then you can find all the books that the current user is interested in with simply `Books.find()`

This will also make your app faster by reducing the number of subscriptions and books you are sending from the server to the client.

Note: over time you might find it confusing to name a collection *Subscriptions* since that term is a core Meteor concept.